# Dojo filtering store with horizontal slider

Tags: dojo

I'm extending the Dylan's store reference to **http://sitepen.github.com/sp-dnd-demo/4-dnd.html** with query capability by adding a horizontal slider against the price of products.

Source @ https://github.com/sitepen/sp-dnd-demo/zipball/gh-pages

Find it difficult to implement slider querying against the store which is not refering to a file store and grid.

**Partial piece of Code for slider**

```
    var slider = new dijit.form.HorizontalSlider({
            name: "slider",
            value: 0,
            minimum: 0,
            count:50,
            maximum: 1100,
            showButtons: true,
            discreteValues:1,
            intermediateChanges: true,
            style: "width:300px;",
            onChange: function(value){

                  console.log("Slider logged" + value);                
                  formattedVal =formatter.format(value, {places:0})  ;

                  console.log("Total " + data.mobile1CatalogData.length);
                  console.log("Formatted Value " + formattedVal);

                  mobile1Store.fetch( { query: {'price': formattedVal },  
                        onItem: function(item) {
                            console.log( mobile1Store.getValue( item, 'description' ) );
                        },
                        onComplete:function(items, request) {
                            console.log(" on Complete" +items.length );
                            mobile1Catalog = util.buildCatalog("mobile1CatalogNode", items, true);
                        },
                        onError: function(e){
                            console.log("Some Issue" + e);
                        }
                });

    });
```

Any pointers on this, highly appreciated.

Thanks.